# Telerik MVC dropdown list Jquery select is 'Undefined'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, dropdownlistfor

I have a Telerik MVC/Kendo dropdown list set up in my view. I'm trying to set the selected value in javascript following their documentation as a guide. Here is my view markup:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="PlantName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Plant:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">

        @code
            Dim listPlants As SelectList = ViewData("listPlants")
            Html.Kendo.DropDownList().Name("Plants").BindTo(listPlants).HtmlAttributes(New With {.Style = "width:100%;", .required = "required"}).render()

        End Code

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
 var test = $('#Plants').data("kendoDropdownList");
```

the variable test is 'undefined'  if i only select:

```
var test = $('#Plants');
```

then it returns the control but i need a reference to the data in the control.  I've done this many times with the telerik mvc grid and it works and i'm following the documentation.  what gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok sorry folks but I found out the problem.  I had a lowercase character where there should have been an uppercase in the jquery select statement.  kendoDropdownList should have been kendoDropDownList.